# What are the default layout settings in gnome-terminal?

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, lxterminal

I want to replace `gnome-terminal` fully by `lxterminal`. I've started by changing the default terminal emulator. So I ran `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`, and chose `lxterminal`. After that, I ran `dconf-editor` and went to `org - gnome - desktop - applications - terminal` and changed `gnome-terminal` to `lxterminal` and removed the `-x` in the `exec arg` part.

The only problem though, is that by default, `lxterminal` doesn't look like `gnome-terminal`. What are `gnome-terminal`'s default layout settings? I'm especially looking for the hexadecimal colour codes for both text and background.

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/

Comment: That page doesn't cover the default colours in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The color by default usually uses the system theme so for ambiance can be seen in the theme folder - gtk-2.0/apps/gnome-terminal.rc & or gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css depending on ubuntu release

gtk-2.0

```
    style "terminal_screen"
{
    text[NORMAL] = "#ffffff"
    base[NORMAL] = "#300a24"

    TerminalScreen::background-darkness = 0.95
```

gtk-3.0 (current on 12.04 - the color: (text) is white & really should be #ffffff

```
    /* gnome-terminal */
TerminalScreen {
-TerminalScreen-background-darkness: 0.95;

    background-color: #300a24;

color: #fff;
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for.